# what does hiding an uneasy conscience with a judicial air mean

Tags: literature

What does hiding an uneasy conscience with a judicial air mean? I've quoted it from Pygmalion, a play by George Bernard Shaw.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: judicial: of, by, or appropriate to a court or judge.

Answer (score 2):

Higgins is *using* "a judicial air" to hide his "uneasy conscience." The broader context [can be seen here](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/pygmalion-31.html); Higgins' housekeeper has scolded him for swearing and he claims that he has never used a certain word. When she stares at him he adds, "hiding an uneasy conscience with a judicial air, 'Except perhaps in a moment of extreme and justifiable excitement.'" In other words, he was uneasy because he knew he *has* used that word, and hid his guilty conscience by adopting an "air"—an attitude—that Shaw describes as "[judicial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judicial)," having to do with judges or legal pronouncement.

There is intentional irony, since Higgins is adopting a "judge-y" tone to cover the fact that he himself is guity.

Comment: In common parlance, a reference something like ***judiciously chosen examples*** doesn't always (maybe not even *usually*) imply *showing **good** judgement* in any kind of *absolute* sense. In my experience, *judiciously chosen examples* usually implies ***cherry-picked** examples* - "good" from the perspective of whoever chose those examples, because they support whatever case he's making. But other people who *don't* agree with the line being presented might well say those examples were ***deviously / misleadingly*** selected. I think it's *that* implication GBS intends.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But as Kate points out, I hastily misread; the original is *judicial*, not *judicious*. Editing...

Comment: thanks alot , but what was the certain word excatly mrs perece asked hegens not to use the word begins with the same letteras bath

Comment: @MoustafaSaad "Bastard" seems the most likely choice, given the character and setting.

Comment: @MoustafaSaad More likely "Bloody"  We know Eliza uses this word because she later says "Walk! Not bloody likely. I am going in a taxi”.  And that line caused a scandal.  Such swearing hadn't previously been heard on the London stage.  Also "bastard" is an insult, and Eliza had no reason to insult anyone because the water was hot. But "bloody" is an intensifier.  Eliza wouldn't call Mrs Pearce a bastard; Eliza is coarse, but not rude. Note that for the musical, "Bloody" was still too strong, and it became "blooming"

Comment: @JamesK Agreed, that makes a lot more sense, especially since it's an adjective rather than a noun. Mrs. Pearce says "you applied it to your boots, to the butter, and to the brown bread," and I thought the construction would be a bit odd.

Comment: thank you all i'm arocky here and i can't figure out how to use the menthin so thanks for all replying i'm egyptian and i'm trying to translat the play into the arbic thank you

Comment: @MoustafaSaad (Wow! Besides simple translation, there's a lot of cultural issues that get lost in translation—it's hard enough to explain some of them to an American audience or a modern one!)